# Problem with getChild while parsing XML with Google Script

Tags: xml, google-apps-script, xml-parsing

Please could anyone help me with this, I'm stuck, I'm trying parse this XML data and insert it into a Google Sheet, I can fetch the XML correctly but after parsing, I'm getting a null with "getChild"..

This is a extract of the XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:etaWebServicesResponse xmlns:ns1="http://ws.ABC.com/ABCws.wsdl" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
            <return xsi:type="xsd:string">
                <PERSONNEL>
                    <INSTRUCTOR>
                        <PERSONNEL_ID>0001</PERSONNEL_ID> 
                        <FIRST_NAME>Mike</FIRST_NAME> 
                    </INSTRUCTOR>
                    <INSTRUCTOR>
                        <PERSONNEL_ID>0002</PERSONNEL_ID> 
                        <FIRST_NAME>Joanna</FIRST_NAME>
                    </INSTRUCTOR>
            </return>
        </ns1:etaWebServicesResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

And I'm trying with this Google App Script

```
function myFunction() {

  var xmlInstructor = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:" + 
  'SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><SOAP-ENV:Body><etaws><operation opstype="instructor">export</operation><parameters><customercode>AAAAAAAA</customercode><accesscode>BBBBBBBBB</accesscode><username>xybvsfsddfas</username></parameters></etaws></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>';

  var url = "https://ABCsystems.com/tseta/servlet/ABC?xmldata=" + xmlInstructor;
  var urlx = encodeURI(url);
  var XMLFetch = UrlFetchApp.fetch(urlx).getContentText();

  var document = XmlService.parse(XMLFetch);

  var documentPretty = XmlService.getPrettyFormat().format(document);
  Logger.log("PrettyFormat:");
  Logger.log(documentPretty);

  Logger.log("Descendants:");
  Logger.log(document.getDescendants());

  var root = document.getRootElement();  
  Logger.log("getRootElement:" + root);

  var instructors = root.getChild("PERSONNEL");
  Logger.log("Personnel:" + instructors);
}
```

The log of document has the XML correctly as shown at the top.

The log of Descendants has the following info (first part):

```xml
[19-05-14 15:12:09:409 PDT] Descendants:
[19-05-14 15:12:09:427 PDT] [[Element: <SOAP-ENV:Envelope [Namespace: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/]/>], [Element: <SOAP-ENV:Body [Namespace: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/]/>], [Element: <ns1:etaWebServicesResponse [Namespace: http://ws.ABCsystems.com/ABC.wsdl]/>], [Element: <return/>], 
, [Element: <PERSONNEL/>], 
 , [Element: <INSTRUCTOR/>], 
  , [Element: <PERSONNEL_ID/>], 0001, 
  , [Element: <FIRST_NAME/>], Mike,
```

The log of getRootElement:

```xml
[19-05-14 15:12:09:428 PDT] getRootElement:[Element: <SOAP-ENV:Envelope [Namespace: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/]/>]
```

and finally instructors = null, I'm not getting to drill down. Any suggestions?

Comment: You want to retrieve values from the XML data at the top of your question. If my understanding is correct, what is ``var url = "https://ABCsystems.com/tseta/servlet/ABC?xmldata=" + xmlInstructor; var urlx = encodeURI(url); var XMLFetch = UrlFetchApp.fetch(urlx).getContentText();``? If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: Sorry maybe it's not too clear.. With that code I fetch the XML, that part is ok. The problem is after parsing, I can't get the data from the XML structure..

Comment: Thank you for replying. Where can I see the retrieved XML data?

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply, it's on the first part of the post (variable XMLFetch)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the result you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the values of `PERSONNEL` from the XML data at the top of your question.

If my understanding is correct, how about this sample script?

#### Modified script:

```
var data = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:etaWebServicesResponse xmlns:ns1="http://ws.ABC.com/ABCws.wsdl" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><return xsi:type="xsd:string"><PERSONNEL><INSTRUCTOR><PERSONNEL_ID>0001</PERSONNEL_ID> <FIRST_NAME>Mike</FIRST_NAME> </INSTRUCTOR><INSTRUCTOR><PERSONNEL_ID>0002</PERSONNEL_ID> <FIRST_NAME>Joanna</FIRST_NAME></INSTRUCTOR></PERSONNEL></return></ns1:etaWebServicesResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>';
var xml = XmlService.parse(data);
var rootChildren = xml.getRootElement().getChildren();
for (var i = 0; i < rootChildren.length; i++) {
  if (rootChildren[i].getName() == "Body" ) {
    var c1 = rootChildren[i].getChildren();
    for (var j = 0; j < c1.length; j++) {
      var c2 = c1[j].getChild("return").getChild("PERSONNEL").getChildren();
      for (var k = 0; k < c2.length; k++) {
        var PERSONNEL_ID = c2[k].getChild("PERSONNEL_ID").getValue();
        var FIRST_NAME = c2[k].getChild("FIRST_NAME").getValue();
        Logger.log("PERSONNEL_ID: %s, FIRST_NAME: %s", PERSONNEL_ID, FIRST_NAME)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- Your XML data at the top of your question is not completed. So in order to use `XmlService.parse()`, I added `</PERSONNEL>` before `</return>`.

#### Reference:

- [Class XmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/xml-service)

Comment: Thanks so much! I really appreciated it!

Comment: @Jean AL I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.